# need to create a related taxonomy stores

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a coupon site, which basically has many vendors in it. I want to create a related stores widget kind of a thing which would display 5-6 stores on the side bar. and i want to them to relate to the current vendor page. till now i have managed to display 5-6 stores links randomly, but i am not able to display the related stores.
 I am using clipper theme in wordpress, and i have kept all my stores in Coupons-Stores and not Post-categories.

```
<?php

$stores = get_terms('stores'); // Note: this returns NULL non-empty cats. It is not normal, could be because of the widget.

// Get all non-empty stores
$nonempty_stores = array();
foreach( $stores as $store )
  if ( !empty( $store ) )
    $nonempty_stores[] = $store;

$stores_count = count($nonempty_stores);

global $random_seed;

// Set initial seed value
$random_seed = $last_update;
if (DISPLAY_SAME_STORES_LIST_FOR_ALL_STORE_PAGES == false)
    $random_seed = $random_seed + $store_catid;

function mtech_rand($min, $max)
{
    global $random_seed;    
    $random_seed = ((1103515245*$random_seed)+12345)%(1<<31);
    return (($random_seed%($max-$min+1))+$min);
}

echo "<div class=\"hdsboxbg\">&nbsp;";

$cntr = 0;
$displayed_cntr = 0;
while (($cntr < $stores_count) && ($displayed_cntr < NUM_OF_RANDOM_STORES_TO_DISPLAY))
{
    $rand_store_idx = mtech_rand($cntr, $stores_count-1);
    $rand_store = $nonempty_stores[$rand_store_idx];
    if (($store_catid == 0) || ($rand_store->cat_ID != $store_catid)) // Random Stores Widget should not display a link to the current store page
    {
        $a_text = $rand_store->name . ' Coupons';
        //$a_text = $rand_store->name;
        echo "<div class=\"hdsmod\"><a href=\"". get_category_link($rand_store->cat_ID) . "\">  $a_text </a></div>";


        $displayed_cntr++;
    }
    $nonempty_stores[$rand_store_idx] = $nonempty_stores[$cntr];
    $nonempty_stores[$cntr] = $rand_store;
    $cntr++;
}

echo "</div>"; 
?>
```

Any other methods are welcome. i have tried to display all the stores like this,

```
$terms = get_terms('stores');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'stores' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
    //We successfully got a link. Print it out.


    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

it displays but i am not able to display the related stores, i am struggling to figure out on which grounds should i proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i would want to display related stores on my sidebar. till now i am able to display stores randomly.

Comment: So are you asking for an algorithm to choose related stories?

Comment: yes preferably a algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'stores';
$args1=array(
    'include'=> array(12,30)
    );

$terms = get_terms('stores',$args1 );
echo '<ul>';


foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'stores' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
    //We successfully got a link. Print it out.


    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```